# Re-representing a point in an affine space via matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ denote a 3-dimensional affine space. Let $\mathbf{\vec{f}}$ denote an affine frame for $A$ of form

$$
\mathbf{\vec{f}} = \begin{bmatrix}
\vec{b_1} & \vec{b_2} & \vec{b_3} & \tilde{o}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and let $\tilde{p}$ denote a point

$$
\tilde{p} = \mathbf{\vec{f}} \mathbf{c}
$$

for $\mathbf{c}$ some $4 \times 1$ (point) column vector.

Suppose now that we re-represent $\tilde{p}$ via a change in frame:

$$
\tilde{p} = \mathbf{\vec{f}} \mathbf{c} = \mathbf{\vec{a}} \mathbf{d}
$$

where

$$
\mathbf{\vec{a}} = \mathbf{\vec{f}} B
$$

with $B$ being an affine matrix.

**Question:** According to a textbook I'm reading, we can say that

$$
\mathbf{d} = B^{-1} \mathbf{c}
$$

Why is this?

Comment: $(fB)(B^{-1}c) = f(BB^{-1})c=fIc = fc$. Is there more substance to your question, or have you just overlooked/messed up the calculation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would be just this :

$\tilde{p} = \mathbf{\vec{f}} \mathbf{c} = \mathbf{\vec{a}} \mathbf{d}$ and $\mathbf{\vec{a}} = \mathbf{\vec{f}} B$ =>

$\tilde{p} = \mathbf{\vec{f}} \mathbf{c} = \mathbf{\vec{f}} B \mathbf{d}$ =>

$ \mathbf{c} =  B \mathbf{d}$ =>

$ B^{-1} \mathbf{c} =  B^{-1} B \mathbf{d}$ =>

$ B^{-1} \mathbf{c} =  \mathbf{d}$

?